# How to load data in hive in structure format

Tags: hive

I have a table say test in hive and having below sample schema:

```
(a String,
b String ,
c String,
d String,
e String)
```

I need to load data from test table to say another table test1 which is having below schema :

```
(a String,
b String,
array < struct < c:String,d:String,e:String>> )
```

How can i load data from test to test1 using hive query

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the hive UDF [inline](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-inline(arrayofstructs)). It will explode the array of structs into multiple rows that you can use in a `SELECT INTO ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need to club the different columns into struct not the vice versa. need to insert  test to test A not vice versa in above example

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using array(named_struct("a",val,"b",bvalue,"c",cvalue))